# PHP error on the Expresso Store inventory tab

Tags: expresso-store, error

Good day dear community. I have a problem when you install the store. at the entrance to the tab store -> inventory, gives me dosing errors. text Errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Addons_modules::$api

Filename: core/Model.php

Line Number: 50


Fatal error: Call to a member function instantiate() on a non-object in /home2/softsltn/public_html/pdq2/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/models/store_model.php on line 611
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What version of EE and Store are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to Store 1.6.4 which is compatible with EE 2.6.